# ActiveAdmin translation_missing in login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In active admin I am using `corp_id` instead of `email` for `Admin User` to login their account. But in login page I am getting incorrect label name as `Title` instead of `corp_id`.I tried to change that label using CSS but it doesn't work for me. How to change the label name of `Title` to `Corp-ID` Please let me know if I were wrong.

[image]

```
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.active_admin.devise.corp_id.title">Title</span>
```

Thanks in advance.

**config/locals/en.yml**

```
# Files in the config/locales directory are used for internationalization
# and are automatically loaded by Rails. If you want to use locales other
# than English, add the necessary files in this directory.
#
# To use the locales, use `I18n.t`:
#
#     I18n.t 'hello'
#
# In views, this is aliased to just `t`:
#
#     <%= t('hello') %>
#
# To use a different locale, set it with `I18n.locale`:
#
#     I18n.locale = :es
#
# This would use the information in config/locales/es.yml.
#
# The following keys must be escaped otherwise they will not be retrieved by
# the default I18n backend:
#
# true, false, on, off, yes, no
#
# Instead, surround them with single quotes.
#
# en:
#   'true': 'foo'
#
# To learn more, please read the Rails Internationalization guide
# available at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html.

en:
  active_admin:
    devise:
      login:
        title: "CorpID"
```

Comment: Can you please share your locale file?

Comment: @Vishal I have shared my local file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Translations are performed in config/locales/en.yml, which override the [values provided by ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml).

Comment: In my config/locales/en.yml I have made my changes like `en:
  active_admin:
    devise:
      login:
        title: "CorpID"` But still am getting title in my login page. Please let me know what I have done here wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the translation in your span. Try this out:

Replace following:

```
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.active_admin.devise.corp_id.title">Title</span>
```

with

```
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.active_admin.devise.corp_id.title"><%= t("active_admin.devise.login.title") %></span>
```

Let me know if you still face the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
en:
  active_admin:
    devise:
      login:
        title: "CorpID"
```

**TO**

```
en:
  active_admin:
    devise:
      corp_id:
        title: "CorpID"
```